# Newton's method of tangents

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I am trying to solve this problem.I need to find a zero of a given function with Newton's method of tangents.The condition is 
`f(x0)*f'(x0)>0` 
and then calculate 
`xn+1=xn-(f(xn)/f'(xn))`
I am now sure that this is the right way to find a zero with the Newton's method of tangents.
If you can check.Thank you.

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 7*x + 6;
For[i = -10, i < 10, i++, 
If[f[i]*f''[i] > 0, Print[i \[Minus] (f[i]/f'[i])]]]
```

Comment: Note that when entering the definition of `f` into Mathematica's front end, you do *not* need to enter the explicit multiplication sign `*` in `7*x`. And you do not need the terminal semicolon (`;`) there, either, since with the use of `:=` you're using a `SetDelayed` rather than the `Set` that would be specified by just `='.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[f, i, x]

f[x_] := x^2 - 7*x + 6;
```

For comparison, the roots are

```
Solve[f[x] == 0, x]

(* {{x -> 1}, {x -> 6}} *)
```

Rather than using [`For`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html), use [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) for a fixed number of iterations

```
NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 3., 20]

(* {3., -3., -0.230769, 0.796987, 0.992376, 0.999988, 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., \
1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)

NestList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 7., 20]

(* {7., 6.14286, 6.00386, 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., \
6., 6., 6., 6., 6.} *)
```

Or use [`FixedPointList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) to stop once the algorithm has converged

```
FixedPointList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 3.]

(* {3., -3., -0.230769, 0.796987, 0.992376, 0.999988, 1., 1., 1.} *)

FixedPointList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 7.]

(* {7., 6.14286, 6.00386, 6., 6., 6., 6.} *)
```

Comment: You might also want to use `NestWhile` or  `NestWhileList`to incorporate a stopping criterion, such as when two successive approximations are sufficiently near one another (absolutely or relatively).